# QRegExp trouble matching pattern

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm attempting to match strings with `QRegExp` in a callback function. I'm using the `C++` implementation of `Qt`. I've written a regular expression of the form: `Atmospheres.(\\d+).(latitude|longitude|radius|path)` and verified it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

The problem is, matching the regular expression with `QRegExp` is always returning a `-1`, a non-match.

Here is some code:

```
QString name = "Atmospheres.1.latitude";
QRegExp regex("Atmospheres.(\\d+).(latitude|longitude|radius|path)");

int pos = 0;
regex.indexIn(name, pos);
```

The above line always returns `-1`. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using Qt 5.x, you should use QRegularExpression instead of QRegExp.

Comment: Using 4.8, but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are running this exact code? It works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QRegExp>

int main()
{
  QString name = "Atmospheres.1.latitude";
  QRegExp regex("Atmospheres.(\\d+).(latitude|longitude|radius|path)");
  int pos = regex.indexIn(name, 0);
  std::cerr << QT_VERSION_STR << ": " << pos << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

executing this produces:

```
5.2.0: 0
```

Comment: It wasn't a `QRegExp` problem at all. I'm initializing the expression in a constructor, but It wasn't being initialized in the particular constructor that I was using. I thought I was taking crazy pills. Thanks for verifying. Here is +15.